# When variable will free in C program

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, ram

In dynamic memory allocation, the memory which is used by `malloc()` and `calloc()` can be freed by using `free()`.
In static memory allocation, when is the variable in `main()` freed from the program?
In a tutorial, I learned that when the whole programs is finished then after all variables are freed from RAM.
But someone tells me that when the program is long enough and variable is used early and after that if the variable has no use in the whole code then compiler will automatically free the variable before the end of program.
Can someone please clarify if both statements are correct or not?

Comment: DMA does _not_ mean dynamic memory allocation, you are mixing up terms incorrectly.

Comment: This might be helpful: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277536)

Comment: I almost want to answer "They are  wrong." But I feel that would not be a helpful answer. So, in order to provide a reasoning and to extract the part where they are not fully wrong, please ask them for details. Especially about what they mean by "long enough", by "early" , by "has no use", by "in the whole code" and by "automactically". Also ask them whether they are precise about "compiler", because the compiler is probably long out of the picture by the time the other qualifiers apply. Also ask them to consider contrasting their statement against the concept of automatic local variables.

Comment: `if the variable has no use in the whole code then compiler will automatically free the variable before the end of program` it's wrong. Global and static variables have defined scope and are not dynamically allocated so there's no need to free them

Comment: You may want to read [C11 6.2.4: Storage durations of objects](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4)

Comment: @pmg An optimizing compiler would optimize the following statements: `a=func(); b=func2(a);` to: `b=func2(func());` if the variable `a` is a local variable that is not used anywhere else in the code. I think in this case, the OP would like to have an answer like: "`a` is 'freed' when calling `func2()`" (because the value is lost then) and not: "`a` is valid until the next `}`."

Answer (score 1):

The language guarantees that the lifetime of a static storage duration variable is the whole program. So it can be safely accessed at any time.

That being said, the standard only requires the code produced by a conformant compiler **to behave as if** all language rules were observed. That means that for optimization purposes a compiler is free to release the memory used by a static variable if it knows that the variable will not be used passed a point. Said differently it is neither required nor forbidden and as a programmer you should not even worry for that except for very specific low level optimization questions.

Example:

```
...
int main() {
    static int arr[10240];
    // uses arr
    ..
    // no uses of arr passed this point - called B
    ...
}
```

The program **shall behave as is** the array `arr` existed from the beginning of the program until its end. But as long as `arr` is not used past point *B*, the compiler **may** reuse its memory, because there will be no change in any observable state.

This in only a low level optimization point allowed (but not required) by the *as if* rule.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this question: [Why does C not require a garbage collector?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/)

Stephen C, the author of the answer says that:

> The culture of these languages (C and C++) is to leave storage
> management to the programmer.

Would the correct answer be when the process is terminated all memory used is freed?  I think yes. C compiler does not look for garbage or non reachable variables, this is a progammer work.

But I have read that C or C++ garbage collectors exists like Java, they can be useful but remember, the implementation will be slower.

Again, I recommend to you read the question I have attached at the beggining for more information.

Comment: "C compiler does not look for garbage or non reachable variables, this is a progammer work." - It typically does.

Comment: When C compiler look for garbage so?

Answer (score 0):

> In a tutorial, I learned that ...

This tutorial is talking about what you as a programmer can see (unless you are debugging your program):

If you write a program, you can rely on the fact that you can read a static variable until the program has finished.

> But someone tells me ...

This person is talking about what is really happening in the background (not visible to the programmer unless you are debugging) when you use an "optimizing" compiler.

> ... when is the variable ... freed from the program?

We have to distinguish between three types of variables:

**Local variables**

Local variables reside on the stack. When the function returns, all memory allocated on the stack during the execution of the function is automatically freed.

For this reason, local variables are freed when the function returns or even earlier.

In the following function:

```
void myFunction(void)
{
    int a, b;
    a = func1();   /* Line "1" */
    func2();
    func3(a);      /* Line "2" */
    b = func4();   /* Line "3" */
    func5();
    func6(b);      /* Line "4" */
}
```

... an "optimizing" C compiler will detect that the variable `a` is not needed any longer when the variable `b` is set. For this reason, it may allocate only enough memory for one `int` variable. This is as if you only defined one variable (`a_and_b`) and the compiler replaced both `a` and `b` by `a_and_b`:

```
int a_and_b;
a_and_b = func1();
...
func6(a_and_b);
```

If you debug the program, the debugger will tell you that variable `b` does not exist when debugging lines "1"-"2"; and it will tell you that variable `a` does not exist when debugging lines "3"-"4".

For this reason, you might say that variable `a` is "freed" after line "2".

**Global variables**

Global variables reside in the `.data` or in the `.bss` section.

On modern desktop computers (on microcontrollers and on MS-DOS computers it is different) the operating system allocates this memory before the program is started and the operating system frees this memory after the program has finished.

Theoretically, it might be possible to optimize global variables the same way as local variables; this means: To use the same memory for two different global variables if one variable is set the first time after the other one is no longer needed.

However, this would be very complicated because a global variable can be accessed from any C source file in the project. For this reason, I doubt that many compilers and linkers have such a feature.

**Static variables**

Variables marked with the keyword `static` are normally also stored in `.data` and `.bss` sections - just like global ones.

However, because they can only be accessed from one C source file (or even from only one function), it is much easier to detect that such a variable is no longer used at a certain point in time.

For this reason, a compiler may optimize a `static` variable the same way as a local variable (so the memory is shared between two variables) or even replace a `static` variable by a local one (on the stack).

One Example:

```
int someFunction()
{
    static int a;
    int b;
    a = func7();
    b = func8(a);       /* Line "5" */
    return b + func9(); /* Line "6" */
}
```

In this case, the program behaves the same way if the variable `a` is not static. For this reason, we can replace `static int` by just `int`.

Now we see that `a` is no longer read after writing to `b`. We can replace the two variables `a` and `b` by one variable `a_and_b`.

If the "optimizing" compiler does this, you will see some message "variable does not exist" in the debugger if you stop your program in line "6" and want to read the value of `a`.

You may say that the variable `a` has been "freed" in line "5".